# Is there any better way to list all the databases in Postgres except database named postgres?

Tags: postgresql, select, where

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false AND datallowconn = true And datname NOT IN ('postgres')
```

Using the code above, I get all the databases except `postgres` as shown in the image below:
[image: All databases in Postgres]

Is there any better/cleaner/nicer way than my code above to get the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real improvement possible, but I think the following is more readable:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE NOT datistemplate
  AND datallowconn
  AND datname <> 'postgres';
```