# How to show number of tables for each database in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, select, table

Related to my previous [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282983/is-there-any-better-way-to-list-all-the-databases-in-postgres-except-database-na), I use the code below to get all databases:

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE NOT datistemplate
  AND datallowconn
  AND datname <> 'postgres';
```

How to get the number of tables from each database returned from the command above?

There is no `master` database in Postgres like Microsoft SQL Server, where I could do a query for all the databases.

Is it possible in Postgres?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following which will list every table (with their row counts) for every schema in the database:

```
select n.nspname as table_schema,
       c.relname as table_name,
       c.reltuples as rows
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace
where c.relkind = 'r'
      and n.nspname not in ('information_schema','pg_catalog')
order by c.reltuples desc;
```

I believe you'll need to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html) in order to run it in every database. Here's a [walkthrough](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-implement-dynamic-sql-in-postgresql-10/).

Comment: How do I pass the database name as a variable into your answer above to show number of table?

Comment: The code above shows all the tables for a database. How do I add the COUNT function to return number of table?

Comment: You can use `COUNT(*) AS TableCount` (similar to Microsoft SQL Server), instead of selecting the other columns I provided.